# Python - Import tweepy ImportError: No module named tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I installed pip install tweepy and it installed without errors.

```
Requirement already satisfied: tweepy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.11.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: PySocks>=1.5.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.11.1->tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.11.1->tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.11.1->tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.11.1->tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=0.6.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->tweepy)
```

Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

consumer_key = 'consumer_key'
consumer_secret = 'consumer_secret'

access_token = 'access_token'
access_token_secret = 'access_token_secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweepy.API('Yunus Hatipoglu')

for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
```

As application, I use Pycharm and my operating system is OSX.

python3 --version: Python 3.6.4

When I run my code, I get the following error:

> import tweepy
>
> ImportError: No module named tweepy

Comment: You have tweepy installed for Python 2.7.  What Python version are you using to run your code?  Perhaps you're actually using Python 3?

Comment: When I check in PyCharm, as project interpreter it uses Python 2.7. I do not use Python3

Comment: To make sure you're not running Python 3, try a simple script that will fail under Python 3, such as `print 'hello'`.

Comment: This might be useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942081/i-cant-import-textblob-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942081/i-cant-import-textblob-package)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> in PyCharm, Settings -> Project Interpreter -> + -> tweepy -> install
>   package.

By doing above, Tweepy has worked in PyCharm terminal.

On the other hand I installed tweepy by typing `python3 -m pip install tweepy`

Answer (score 5):

Try Installing though this command:

```
python3 -m pip install tweepy
```

Comment: This one worked. When I run my code on terminal, it works but when I run in PyCharm application, I still get the same error

Comment: You might are using different environment in pycharm. Which doesn't know where you installed it.

Answer (score 3):

I had it installed directly in the Python Folder and it didn't work for me.

After that, I uninstalled using: `pip uninstall tweepy` at the same prompt.

So, I used Anaconda prompt and after code: `pip install tweepy` it worked for me.

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu try:
`sudo apt install python-pip`

and then run:
`python3 -m pip install tweepy`

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will improve my answers from next time 

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens where You might using the different python environments in pycharm. Your computer may have different python interpreters as you install pip several times. 
Try to config the exact python interpreter using the following steps. 
PyCharm, Settings -> Project Interpreter -> 
 This will show the installed package list and dedicated interpreter at the top right-hand side. Try your right interpreter within the dropdown. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04

```
   pip3 install --user tweepy
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Windows You can do.

```
pip install tweepy
```

Alternatively, you may clone it from the github source.

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
pip install .
```