# I cant import textblob package

Tags: python, pip, spyder, textblob

I installed textblob using the command `pip install`. But now I am trying to import it and I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob'

I am using Spyder in a windows 10 system

```
from textblob import TextBlob
```

> C:\Users\Diego>pip install textblob Requirement already satisfied: textblob in c:\users\diego\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (0.15.2) Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.1 in c:\users\diego\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from textblob) (3.4) Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\diego\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (1.11.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in c:\users\diego\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (3.4.0.3)

Comment: Is your environmental path correct?
Did the pip install completed successfully?

Comment: I think so, I am getting this now: C:\Users\Diego>pip install textblob
Requirement already satisfied: textblob in c:\users\diego\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.1 in c:\users\diego\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from textblob) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\diego\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (1.11.0)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in c:\users\diego\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (3.4.0.3)

Comment: Do you have issues with importing other modules?

Comment: No, pandas for example works fine

Comment: However I also cant import package tabulate

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why but the solution was to install textblob from the spyder console using:

```
!pip install textblob
```